# Outlook 365 -- what time zone is displayed in calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I work with a team across several time zones.

I also travel a lot.

I find the calendar completely confusing , as in most places the time zone is not mentioned.

How does Outlook work in this regard?

[image]

Comment: The time zone of an event for that calendar will be of that of whoever created the Calendar originally.  You should be looking at the timezone of the event.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, that does not help. When I look at other peoples' calendars, I see busy times, but  because of issue above I have no idea the time zone of the busy periods.

Comment: There isn’t a way to tell unless you look at the event itself

Comment: You’re really overthinking this maybe. All events are displayed in your local time so you don’t have to think about it.